# Compose: how to change statusbar color only for specified screen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar

I have an application, where all of screens except 2-3 screens have the same statusbar color.

So the purpose is to change statusbar color when this screen is opened and reset statusbar color to default color from theme when this screen is closed.

I am trying to implement it with `DisposableEffect`:

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = anotherColor)
    onDispose {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = defaultColor)
    }
}
```

It works, but with delays, not synchronously with TopAppBar:

[image]

What is the way to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the delay is inevitable, I've never seen it change instantly.

I always opt-in for a transparent status bar + draw behind systembars and handle everything on my own. And drawing behind system bars is the new recommended approach. Since you are already using compose, this is very easy with help of accompanist lib + compose 1.2.0 has inset modifiers built in to help with this.

request your activity to be laid out edge-to-edge (draw behind system bars)

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}
```

Using accompanist UIController lib, set status bar colors to transparent.

```kotlin
systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
    color = Color.Transparent,
    darkIcons = useDarkIcons
)
```

In your composables, where needed, consume the appropriate insets.

```kotlin
Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .statusBarsPadding() //status bar insets
        .navigationBarsPadding() //nav bar insets
        .systemBarsPadding() //both
```

EDIT: you could create a disposable effect wrapper to switch system icons, and use it everywhere you need. For example: (you can improve this)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun initSystemUi(
    useDarkIcons: Boolean = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight,
    systemUiController: SystemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )
        onDispose {
            systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                darkIcons = useDarkIcons
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this approach. But what about icons colors? In which moment you will change icons color from dark to light or vice versa?

Comment: I do that per root composable destination, as needed. I created a wrapper composable around a disposable effect like you did, and add that everywhere I need.

Comment: I have edited and added an example compose helper.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to add this code snippet for each of your screens, there will be no delay, as far as I can see on my phone. Basically you set your color locally rather than for the whole app / theme.

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
SideEffect {
    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
        color = aColor
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. there was only one problem with navigate to other screens in which I did handle that in my navigation graphs for every single screen in my feature modules. without any lags or delay.

Answer (score -1):

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

{isFocused ?
<StatusBar backgroundColor='#74ADA2' barStyle='dark-content' />
: 
null}
```